# Can a UWP app act as a SignalR server?

Tags: c#, signalr, uwp

I saw a code sample that makes a WPF app a SignalR server: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

Can I make my UWP app a SignalR server? So that other clients can connect to someone running a UWP app on their device?

I tried installing the SignalR NuGet on to my UWP app, but I got an error:

```
Install-Package : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.


At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I am also thinking about running a SignalR server as a service and then connecting the UWP app to it and connecting other clients to the service. Will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR uses server APIs that are not available on UWP, so I doubt this will work, despite I have not looked into it in more detail.

But it is in general not a good idea to do that anyway the way UWP apps work. For example, they get suspended when they are not in the foreground, which should never happen to anything that is a server. You can definitely not rely on it to be available permanently. Is there a specific reason you considered a UWP app for doing this?

So your approach by using a (Windows?) service to host SignalR and connecting the UWP app (and possible other UWP apps) to it is the much better and in fact the correct approach. Another option is to host a web application in IIS or any web server you prefer instead of a Windows service, as handling is a bit easier than self-host a web service inside a Windows service.

Comment: UWP apps can run in the foreground on a Raspberry Pi until the pi is shut off, so this is valid use case.

Comment: @StuartSmith I still would not recommend it and if the OP would have had such a special use case, I think he would have mentioned it. But that's the reason I asked if he has such a special use case, to be sure.